# Two formulas I'm having issues with

Tags: excel

### this is my first time asking a question here, but I have two formulas that I'm not really sure why they aren't working.

The first issue I'm having is with this formula:

`=MAX(IF(C46:C51<80,B46:B51))`

Any reason that this formula returns #VALUE! I'm supposed to find the max value of data in column B so long as the data in column C is less than 80.

---

Then I'm having issues with VLOOKUP on two questions, that are related I have a large dataset on a separate worksheet. I need to VLOOKUP someone's name to find a value associated with that name. The problem is that their name comes up multiple times. The formula I have for it so far is:

`=VLOOKUP('PDR DATA'!E80,'PDR DATA'!A4:V119,15,FALSE)`

Where 'PDR DATA'!E80 is the first instance of the person's name appearing. However, using FALSE with VLOOKUP returns #N/A, but if I use TRUE it returns the very last value from column 15 even though the name is different from what I'm searching for. I'm lost here and don't know where to turn.

Comment: try this.  =MAX(IF(C46:C51<80,B46:B51,C46:C51))  because IF has three inputs IF(Condition, true statement, false statement) you didn't mention the false part

Comment: can you give me some sample data or screenshot for vlookup issue?

Comment: First formula works for me.  I put a bunch of data in B46:C51, and the maximum B column value where the C column value is less than 80 is displayed and changes if I change the data.. With the second formula, I suggest the first argument (`lookup_value` in the formula) shouldn't be in the searching array (`table_array`)

Comment: Okay so I use this to reply, right? The first thing, adding a third input, doesn't seem to work. You're saying that the first formula works for you? Let me screenshot both datasets and see if you can figure it out.

Comment: Okay, so this dataset is for the first formula: [link](https://imgur.com/jLiRmSV) and this dataset is for the second formula: [link](https://imgur.com/4nyBvKd).

Comment: can you give me your formula after added third input?

Comment: `=MAX(IF(C46:C51<80,B46:B51,C46:C51))`

Comment: It is working for me. Please recheck your excel

Comment: What else should I check? Can you at least give me some help with the second formula?

Comment: =VLOOKUP(cell you want to lookup for, cells where you want to lookup(maybe more than one column), which column you want to fetch from (number), rangelookup) try to understand the syntax and give your inputs.

Comment: Well I think I understand the syntax, because I was able to successfully use the formula on three different datasets inside of the worksheet, it's just this dataset I'm using is a different worksheet and also includes many instances of the cell I want to lookup for.

Answer (score 0):

1. =MAX(IF(C46:C51<80,B46:B51,C46:C51)) works for me. (Please ensure B46:B51 & C46:C51 has integer values)
2. =VLOOKUP(cell you want to lookup for, cells where you want to lookup(maybe more than one column), which column you want to fetch from (number), rangelookup) try to understand the syntax and give your inputs

ex: If I have a existing data with Name and id in sheet2, need that id in sheet1 by using the name then I will use =VLOOKUP(L2,Sheet2!A2:B5,2,TRUE)

L2 is the sheet1 name, then I have selected both columns(A,B) and rows in sheet2, then column number is 2.